# How to fix dependency error with React App using Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, yarnpkg

So I installed Jest in a new project and the app stopped running, due to the error below.

**Summary:** It's telling me that I've manually installed a dependency to `node_modules`, something I didn't do, and it's asking me to delete my entire `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`. But those steps aren't working.

**Note:** Removing the dependency from `package.json` then deleting `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` does fix the problem, but when I install `jest` again, it falls into the same problem.

The steps I took to install jest, [here](https://jestjs.io/pt-BR/docs/tutorial-react):

```sh
$ yarn add --dev react-test-renderer
$ yarn add --dev jest babel-jest @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react react-test-renderer
```

The error message

```sh
$ react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "jest": "26.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\WORK\plotting-a-chart\node_modules\jest (version: 26.6.3)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\WORK\plotting-a-chart\node_modules\jest is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!
```

I tried doing all the steps, I already use `yarn`, I even cleared my yarn cache before doing the steps 1 to 4.

1. Delete `package-lock.json` (not package.json!) and/or `yarn.lock` in your project folder;
2. Delete `node_modules` in your project folder;
3. Remove "jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the `package.json` file in your project folder;
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

I'm out of ideas.

```json
// package.json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.23.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.5",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-resizable": "^1.11.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "unit": "jest"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
   presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
 };
```

Comment: It's still in your `devDependencies`?

Comment: When ? If I delete node_modules and remove it from package.json no it's not. But if I install jest again it is.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The whole problem is a Jest version mismatch. You're explicitly putting it in `devDependencies` and the error message says not to (#3 in your list).

Comment: The problem is, i'm already using the lastest version 26.6.3, it claims im using another one.

Comment: And it tells you why.

Comment: Yes but shouldn't I be using the latest version, are you suggesting to downgrade ?

Comment: CRA has its own dependencies. If you don't want to use what it defines then you'd need to eject the app and update its dependencies (or update CRA which might have more recent versions). That is what the message is telling you: "The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires..." and "Don't try to install it manually [...]" which is what you did.

Comment: I didn't say anything not explicitly in the output in your question. I pretty much just read it back to you.

Comment: Read from "The react-scripts package provided [...]" up until the line w/ the Windows pathname.

Comment: You can also install jest under an npm alias so it will co-exist with the version that is installed as a dependency of react-scripts.

Comment: output from `npm ls jest` suggests that react-scripts@4.0.3 depends on two versions of the jest lib.
 react-scripts@4.0.3 -> jest-watch-typeahead@0.6.1 -> jest@26.6.3 AND react-scripts@4.0.3 -> jest@26.6.0

Apparently, jest is included in two different versions from react-scripts itself?

Comment: That seems like it, the entire issue was that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to npm install jest. The error is telling you :

> Don't try to install it manually.

Here is what it says on [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-environments.html)

> If you use Create React App, Jest is already included out of the box
> with useful defaults.

To solve your issue you should run this :

```
npm uninstall --save-dev jest
npm uninstall --save jest
rm node_modules 
npm i
```

Answer (score 2):

I did solved this issue by creating a `.env` file in the project folder, with `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`, and now the test runner seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: You really don't need to install jest, that was the problem, React has jest bult-in, but yea that works too.

Answer (score 1):

When I encountered this problem, I used the stack trace to figure out what version of jest it was looking for. I then yarn removed it and reinstalled the version it wanted. Just to be safe I would do the entire process it suggests but make sure you install the version it asks for